# String to byte[] with the right encoding

Tags: java, encoding

I am trying to test a piece of code for char set decoding (third-party lib). 
I have wrote an input strings like this:

```
private static String czech = "Český";
private static String japanese = "日本語";
private static String german = "Entwickeln Sie mit Vergnügen";
private static  String china = "愉快地發展";
```

Now I am trying to get a byte array ( byte[] ) from this strings.
How to do it correctly?? For example I have tried

```
byte bb = japanese.getBytes(Charset.forName("EUC-JP")); 
// because EUC-JP
// EUC_JP JISX 0201, 0208 and 0212, EUC encoding Japanese 
// from [http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/intl/encoding.doc.html][1]
```

But it seems not right, because the default UTF-8 was returned as result.
Perhaps the input string is too short or I have used a wrong encoding name?

*The test works like this:

```
  String encodingName = testerOfEncoding(bb); // default UTF-8 (if could not detect) =)
```

Comment: What do you mean with "it seems not right", which method you use depends on your needs. If you need UTF-8, use UTF-8, if you need a different character set, use a different character set. However the real problem seems to be that you try to detect the character set based on a byte array: There is no real way to decide the character set from that (although you can apply some heuristics).

Comment: This tool works with byte arrays as input(

Comment: That doesn't clarify anything about your question